# Hadoop/MR temporary directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've been struggling with getting Hadoop and Map/Reduce to start using a separate temporary directory instead of the /tmp on my root directory.

I've added the following to my core-site.xml config file:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/data/tmp</value>
</property>
```

I've added the following to my mapreduce-site.xml config file:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.cluster.local.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.system.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/system</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/staging</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir</name>
   <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/temp</value>
</property>
```

No matter what job I run though, it's still doing all of the intermediate work out in the /tmp directory.  I've been watching it do it via df -h and when I go in there, there are all of the temporary files it creates.

Am I missing something from the config?

This is on a 10 node Linux CentOS cluster running 2.1.0.2.0.6.0 of Hadoop/Yarn Mapreduce.

EDIT:
After some further research, the settings seem to be working on my management and namednode/secondarynamed nodes boxes.  It is only on the data nodes that this is not working and it is only with the mapreduce temporary output files that are still going to /tmp on my root drive, not the my data mount where I have set in the configuration files.

Comment: Have you made the change in each of the config files (in each of the nodes)? The nodes pick up their own config files, not the master node ones.

Comment: We are using Ambari to administer the cluster and it takes care of pushing out the changes to all of the other nodes from the management node.  I verified after I made the changes that all nodes core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml files had the same config changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Hadoop 2.0, then the proper name of the config file you need to change is `mapred-site.xml`, not `mapreduce-site.xml`.

An example can be found on the Apache site: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

and it uses the `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir` property name, with a default value of `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local`

Try renaming your `mapreduce-site.xml` file to `mapred-site.xml` in your `/etc/hadoop/conf/` directories and see if that fixes it.

If you are using *Ambari*, you should be able to just go to use the "Add Property" button on the MapReduce2 / Custom mapred-site.xml section, enter 'mapreduce.cluster.local.dir' for the property name, and a comma separated list of directories  you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify this property in hdfs-site.xml rather than core-site.xml.Try setting this property in hdfs-site.xml. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: There were a bunch of directory settings in there, however, that hadoop.tmp.dir was not listed as a valid property per this page:

Comment: [HDFS-SITE.XML Properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Comment: I think you should try adding it in hdfs-site.xml and then check if it works

Comment: Tried adding it.  Mapreduce jobs are still using the main /tmp directory instead of the one in the config.  Thanks though.

Comment: I think you should try restarting the daemon services and check if it works

Comment: When I made the change before, I stopped all of my services for my cluster, made the change and started the services.  That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The mapreduce properties should be in mapred-site.xml.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue where some nodes would not honor the hadoop.tmp.dir set in the config.

A reboot of the misbehaving nodes fixed it for me.