# Missing staging directory in Hadoop Yarn

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup hadoop-3.0.0(Yarn and Map Reduce) for the first time. I want to see JobHistory logs of the system, which can be fed as input to [Rumen](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-rumen/Rumen.html).

I am doing my execution in [Pseudo-Distributed_Operation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation).

I have enabled Yarn log aggregation as suggested [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ref-375ff479-e530-46d8-9f96-8b52dadb5183.1.html).

[This](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201925118-How-to-Find-and-Review-Logs-for-Yarn-MapReduce-Jobs) article talks about where the logs can be found. It says that it is in the following directory in hdfs.

```
/user/uname/.staging/job_id/
```

However, I am not able to find this directory. Following is what I get as the error message.

```
bin/hdfs dfs -ls /user/uname/.staging
ls: `/user/uname/.staging': No such file or directory
```

I tried searching for the /user/uname/.staging in the local file system too. However, I got the same directory doesn't exist error.(This was obvious as I didn't create any.) However, I have created /user/uname in the HDFS system(while doing the setup and /user/uname/ does exist but the .staging sub directory in it is not found).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644725/hadoop-mr-temporary-directory) stackoverflow answer does talk about the similar issue, but is not very clear that how can I adapt it to my problem and also this is for an older version of Hadoop and it appears that it will not work for Hadoop-3.0.0

Any help would be appreciated.